# PythonでCSVファイルをYAMLに変換したいが、上手く出力されない

Tags: python, csv, yaml

PythonでCSVをYAMLに変換したいのですが、想定した通りに出力されません。

##### CSVファイル

```
version,3
services,
db,
container_name,atcoder-stream-db
image,postgres:12.1
expose,"- ""5432"""

web-backend,
container_name,atcoder-stream-backend
build,
context,./atcoder-stream-backend
dockerfile,Dockerfile
volumes
,- ./atcoder-stream-backend/atcoder-stream-api
,- ./atcoder-stream-backend/libraries/lib/lib
,- ./atcoder-stream-backend/libraries/twitterapi/twitterapi
ports," - ""8000:8000"""
depends_on, - db
command,"sh -c ""python /app/src/atcoder-stream-api/manage.py migrate && python"
web-frontend,
container_name,atcoder-stream-frontend
build,
context,./atcoder-stream-frontend
dockerfil,Dockerfile
volumes,
,- ./atcoder-stream-frontend:/app
port," - ""3000:3000"""
command," sh -c ""cd /app && yarn start"""
```

##### 想定しているYAMLファイル

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    container_name: atcoder-stream-db
    image: postgres:12.1
    expose:
      - "5432"

  web-backend:
    container_name: atcoder-stream-backend
    build:
      context: ./atcoder-stream-backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./atcoder-stream-backend/atcoder-stream-api
      - ./atcoder-stream-backend/libraries/lib/lib
      - ./atcoder-stream-backend/libraries/twitterapi/twitterapi
    ports:
      # host:container
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    command: sh -c "python /app/src/atcoder-stream-api/manage.py migrate && python /app/src/atcoder-stream-api/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"

  web-frontend:
    container_name: atcoder-stream-frontend
    build:
      context: ./atcoder-stream-frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./atcoder-stream-frontend:/app
    ports:
      # host:container
      - "3000:3000"
    command: sh -c "cd /app && yarn start"
```

Pythonでは以下のように記述しました。

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
import yaml

path = Path('keywords.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(path, encoding='cp932')
# print(df)
# path2 = Path('data2.csv')
# df.to_csv(path2, encoding='cp932', index=False)
# print(df)
df = pd.read_csv(path, encoding='cp932',index_col=0, header=None, na_filter=False)
with open('config.yml','w') as yaml_file:
    yaml.dump(
        df.to_dict(orient='dict'),
        yaml_file,
        sort_keys=False,
    )
```

##### 現状の出力結果

```
1:
  version: '3'
  services: ''
  db: ''
  container_name: atcoder-stream-frontend
  image: postgres:12.1
  expose: '- "5432"'
  web-backend: ''
  build: ''
  context: ./atcoder-stream-frontend
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
  volumes: ''
  ? ''
  : '- ./atcoder-stream-frontend:/app'
  ports: ' - "8000:8000"'
  depends_on: ' - db'
  command: ' sh -c "cd /app && yarn start"'
  web-frontend: ''
  dockerfil: Dockerfile
  port: ' - "3000:3000"'
```

##### 問題点

- 空白行に `''` があり、削除したい。
- dbとweb-backend:にcontainer_nameがあるのですがweb-backendでは認識され表示されません。
- value配下のデータが出力されません。

csvの記述に問題があるのでしょうか？

YAMLからCSVに変換する情報があるのですが、私のような方法の情報が少ない。

Comment: おそらくこの記事 [PythonでcsvファイルをＹａｍｌに変換したい。](https://teratail.com/questions/pcbmzwus0wbe9t) の結果の後で発生した課題と思われますが、前提となる目的や条件などの説明をこちらの質問でも記述しておいた方が良いでしょう。

Comment: YAML を直接記述した方が見やすく簡単な気もしますが、敢えて CSV から YAML に変換を行おうとしているのは何故でしょうか？ (Excel から出力したい？) / 出力結果で必要なインデントが考慮されていないので、その辺りの変換ルールを決める必要がありそうです。

Comment: 現在のCSVの変換ルールをきちんと質問に書いたほうがいいと思います。CSVを見る限り、「一列目の項目がキー、2列目が値」「2列目が空の場合は一列目をキー、それ以下を空白行が発生するまでの次階層の配列を値とする」「一列目が空の場合は前の項目の続く値とする」があるかなと思います。それ以外にもあれば

Comment: CSV→YAMLにするのではなくて一旦pythonの配列に変換して問題を切り分けたほうがいいと思います。CSVのほうにも問題ありそうだし、YAMLの変換も問題ありそうです。「CSV→pythonの配列」「pythonの配列→YAML」それぞれでやってみて、読み込みと書き込みを別の問題としてとらえてもう少し問題を細かく分割していくとわかりやすいと思います

Comment: ありがとうございます。見直します。

Answer (score 0):

だいたいの原因はcsvの構成が多くの項目を同一レベルでフラットに書いているためでしょう。

- 空白行に `''` があり、削除したい。
  →おそらくCSVに空白行があるからでしょうね。CSVの空白行を削れば良いと思われます。
- dbとweb-backend:にcontainer_nameがあるのですがweb-backendでは認識され表示されません。
  →それらの項目をフラットに書いているため同じ名前があると後からの値に置き換えられてしまうからですね。
- value配下のデータが出力されません。
  →`value`ではなく`volumes`のtypoでしょうね。
  pandas DataFrameの`to_dict()`でどのような変換が為されるか、目的の.ymlを得るためにはどのようなDataFrame/dictionaryの構成にすれば良いか、そのためにCSVはどうすれば良いかを知って対応する必要があるでしょう。

---

質問や上記の内容を考えると、単純なpandas DataFrameの`to_dict()`だけで目的の.ymlを得るのは難しいと思われます。

以下のようなサイトがあり、「想定しているYAMLファイル」を入れて変換させてみるとCSVは出来ませんでしたがJSONは出来ました。
[Best Online YAML Converter](https://codebeautify.org/yaml-to-json-xml-csv/)
上記ページの結果がこうなったので、これに相当するdictionaryが作れれば、.ymlを得ることが出来ると考えられます。

```
{
    "version": "3",
    "services": {
        "db": {
            "container_name": "atcoder-stream-db",
            "image": "postgres:12.1",
            "expose": [
                "5432"
            ]
        },
        "web-backend": {
            "container_name": "atcoder-stream-backend",
            "build": {
                "context": "./atcoder-stream-backend",
                "dockerfile": "Dockerfile"
            },
            "volumes": [
                "./atcoder-stream-backend/atcoder-stream-api",
                "./atcoder-stream-backend/libraries/lib/lib",
                "./atcoder-stream-backend/libraries/twitterapi/twitterapi"
            ],
            "ports": [
                "8000:8000"
            ],
            "depends_on": [
                "db"
            ],
            "command": "sh -c \"python /app/src/atcoder-stream-api/manage.py migrate && python /app/src/atcoder-stream-api/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000\""
        },
        "web-frontend": {
            "container_name": "atcoder-stream-frontend",
            "build": {
                "context": "./atcoder-stream-frontend",
                "dockerfile": "Dockerfile"
            },
            "volumes": [
                "./atcoder-stream-frontend:/app"
            ],
            "ports": [
                "3000:3000"
            ],
            "command": "sh -c \"cd /app && yarn start\""
        }
    }
}
```

このようなネストしたり途中にリスト(配列)があるようなデータを作成するためにはCSVの方もそれを考慮した構成が必要でしょうし、一部だけをリスト(配列)化するためには単純な`to_dict()`だけででは難しそうで、それなりの処理が必要と思われます。

あと、PyYAMLモジュールではそのままだと文字列がシングルクォーテーションで表現されるので使い分けしたい場合は工夫が必要になります。
多くの記事で`ruamel.yaml`を使う回答が簡単そうなので、それを応用します。
[Python-yaml script and double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67476386/9014308)
[How to print a value with double quotes and spaces in YAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47542343/9014308)
[Python YAML dumper single quote and double quote issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53606252/9014308)
[Python yaml generate few values in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52423986/9014308)

---

作成する元データは、例えばExcelだとこんな感じの表が考えられます。
[image: ExcelImage]

それと対応したCSVはこちらになります。

```
version,"""3""",,,
services,db,,,
,,container_name,atcoder-stream-db,
,,image,postgres:12.1,
,,expose,"- ""5432""",
,web-backend,container_name,atcoder-stream-backend,
,,build,context,./atcoder-stream-backend
,,,dockerfile,Dockerfile
,,volumes,- ./atcoder-stream-backend/atcoder-stream-api,
,,,- ./atcoder-stream-backend/libraries/lib/lib,
,,,- ./atcoder-stream-backend/libraries/twitterapi/twitterapi,
,,ports," - ""8000:8000""",
,,depends_on,- db,
,,command,"sh -c ""python /app/src/atcoder-stream-api/manage.py migrate && python /app/src/atcoder-stream-api/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000""",
,web-frontend,container_name,atcoder-stream-frontend,
,,build,context,./atcoder-stream-frontend
,,,dockerfil,Dockerfile
,,volumes,- ./atcoder-stream-frontend:/app,
,,port," - ""3000:3000""",
,,command," sh -c ""cd /app && yarn start""",
```

---

Pythonスクリプトはこんな感じで、読み込んだCSVの空欄を埋めて、groupbyで切り出して、ネストされた構造的なdictionaryを組み立てていく形です。
質問の.ymlに特化した逐次処理のプログラムですので、突っ込みどころは多々あるでしょうが、まずは出来ることを目指すとこんな感じになります。

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml
from ruamel.yaml.scalarstring import DoubleQuotedScalarString as dq
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(sequence=4, offset=2)
yaml.width = 1024

path = Path('keywords.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(path, encoding='cp932', header=None, skipinitialspace=True, dtype='str')
for n in range(3):
  df[n].fillna(method='ffill',inplace=True)
df.fillna('',inplace=True)

def df_to_dict(frame, currentindex, yamldict):
    nextindex = currentindex + 1
    for key,workframe in frame.groupby(by=currentindex, sort=False):
        value = workframe.at[workframe.index.values[0],nextindex].strip()
        if len(workframe) == 1:
            if value:
                uselist = False
                if value.startswith('- '):
                    value = value[2:]
                    uselist = True
                if value.startswith('"'):
                    value = dq(value.strip('"'))
                if uselist:
                    value = [value]
                yamldict[key] = value
        elif value.startswith('- '):
            values = [v.strip()[2:] for v in workframe[nextindex].tolist()]
            yamldict[key] = values
        else:
            work2frame = workframe.iloc[:,workframe.columns!=currentindex]
            workdict = {}
            df_to_dict(work2frame, nextindex, workdict)
            yamldict[key] = workdict

yamldict = {}
df_to_dict(df, 0, yamldict)

with open('config.yml','w') as yaml_file:
    yaml.dump(
        yamldict,
        yaml_file,
    )
```

結果のファイルは以下になります。

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    container_name: atcoder-stream-db
    image: postgres:12.1
    expose:
      - "5432"
  web-backend:
    container_name: atcoder-stream-backend
    build:
      context: ./atcoder-stream-backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./atcoder-stream-backend/atcoder-stream-api
      - ./atcoder-stream-backend/libraries/lib/lib
      - ./atcoder-stream-backend/libraries/twitterapi/twitterapi
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    command: sh -c "python /app/src/atcoder-stream-api/manage.py migrate && python /app/src/atcoder-stream-api/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
  web-frontend:
    container_name: atcoder-stream-frontend
    build:
      context: ./atcoder-stream-frontend
      dockerfil: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./atcoder-stream-frontend:/app
    port:
      - "3000:3000"
    command: sh -c "cd /app && yarn start"
```